# How can i select the div id in Selenium 2 WebDriver?

Tags: c#, html, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I want to find a tag in selenium 2 with C#, but I can't get access to div tag with id or xpath or etc. This is my code:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("captcha"));
```

and the web source is:

```
<body id="mainBody">
<div class="top_bar" style="min-height:210px">
    <div class="m_sidebar_view">
        <div id="captcha" style="position: relative; float: right; margin: 6px 35px 0 0; overflow: auto;"><div/>  
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: try this xpath:  " //div[@class='top_bar"]/div/div "

Comment: What you trying with it ?

Answer (score 1):

Captcha is often loaded within an `iframe` (see, for instance, the [google recaptcha demo](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo) source code). *Switch to it* before searching for the captcha element:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame("frame_name_or_id");
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it's unclear what your problem is, one of the most popular mistakes is not waiting for the element. So try [to wait](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp):

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement myDynamicElement = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
{
    return d.FindElement(By.Id("captcha"));
});
```

Comment: thank for ur answer bro. but im sure my problem is not waiting. the web driver can not find the element with this id. i dont know why